# AttributedStringとRegexを使って文字列内のURLにリンクをつけたい

Tags: swift, swiftui

`https://google.com/ hello https://google.com/ https://google.com/`という文字列があった際に`SwiftUI.Text`でリンク付きで表示させたいです。

以下のようにAttributedStringとRegexで実装したのですが、最初の`https://google.com/`にしかリンクがつきません

原因は`AttributedString.range(of:)`が1つ目にしかマッチしないことだとはわかっているのですが、対処法がわかりません。

`Range<AttributedString.Index>`から`Range<String.Index>`の変換できればできればいいのですが、わかりませんでした。

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RegexBuilder

struct ContentView: View {
  var attributedString: AttributedString {
    let inputText: String = "https://google.com/ hello https://google.com/ https://google.com/"
    var attributedText = AttributedString(inputText)

    let regex = Regex {
      OneOrMore(.url())
    }

    for match in inputText.matches(of: regex) {
      let range = attributedText.range(of: match.0)!
      attributedText[range].link = URL(string: String(match.0))!
    }

    return attributedText
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(attributedString)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://zenn.dev/en3_hcl/articles/34ae63714a4daf の記事で紹介されている以下を使えば全てのrangeを取れるようです。

```swift
extension AttributedString {
    func ranges<T: StringProtocol>(of stringToFind: T) -> [Range<AttributedString.Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<AttributedString.Index>] = []
        var substring = self[self.startIndex ..< self.endIndex]
        while let range = substring.range(of: stringToFind) {
        ranges.append(range)
            substring = self[range.upperBound...]
    }
        return ranges
    }
}
```